# Spring MVC test with MockMvc

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mocking, spring-mvc-test

I'm trying to run a test for testing a Spring MVC controller. The test compile and runs, but my problem is that I got a PageNotFound warning:

```
WARN  PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/] in DispatcherServlet with name ''
```

My really simple test as follows:

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.view;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration({
  "classpath*:/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml",
  "classpath*:/WEB-INF/serviceContext.xml"
})
public class FrontPageControllerTest {

@Autowired 
private WebApplicationContext ctx;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before  
public void init() {  
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.ctx).build();
}  

@Test
public void frontPageController() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
    .andDo(print())
    .andExpect(status().isOk())  
    .andExpect(view().name("searchfrontpage"));       
  }
}
```

I'm 100% sure that my webapp maps to the frontpage at "/" and that the name on the view is "searchfrontpage".

Please help!

Answer (score 7):

Another easier way to solve the issue is to change init to this :

```
mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new FrontPageController()).build();
```

Answer (score 5):

My ContextConfiguration was wrong. Correct was:

```
@ContextConfiguration({
  "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml",
  "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/serviceContext.xml"
})
```

Now everything works fine.

Comment: @jorgen Could you provide the contents of your applicationContext.xml and serviceContext.xml files?